# How do I filter an array of arrays using dynamically generated values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, filter

I have a dataset in the following format, it's an array of arrays called filtered_data

```
["docmetaID", "pathwaySeqID", "srcstrID", "accstrID", "processDescription", "productID", "collection", "doctype", "studytype"]
["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Adsorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]
["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Desorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]
["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Precipitation", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]
```

I can filter this array for a specific column, say processDescription by using:

```
filtered_data = parsed.data.filter(function(result) { 
      return result[5] === 'Adsorption';
})
```

However I would like to do multiple filters but that are generated dynamically, such that I go through a loop and just add what i need to the return statement, like below:

```
filtered_data = filtered_data.filter(function(result) { 
      return result[5] === 'Adsorption' || result[5] === 'Desorption' && results[6] === 'PREC'
})
```

I have experimented with a few ideas including possibly using eval() to generate the return statement. Other examples I've seen have been using an array of objects for their dataset and not an array of arrays like mine and use .every() but I just can't seem to apply it to my case.

I also thought about running the filter for each iteration and pushing the results into another array but that seems a bit clumsy.

Note that I will need the condition to be OR or AND depending on the filter type, filter type being result[6] or result[5] etc. For example:

```
&& results[6] === 'PREC'
```

is AND from the but result[5] needs to be OR from the example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the data structure you have is not very object oriented. It's more like CSV format. I would suggest converting it to an array of objects:

```js
let data = [
  ["docmetaID", "pathwaySeqID", "srcstrID", "accstrID", "processDescription", "productID", "collection", "doctype", "studytype"],
  ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Adsorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""],
  ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Desorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""],
  ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Precipitation", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]
];

let [header, ...rows] = data;
let arr = rows.map(row => Object.fromEntries(
  row.map((val, i) => [header[i], val])
));

console.log(arr);
```

Then, you could format your filters as objects too, which would have the same properties. For instance, the filter you have in your example:

```
result[5] === 'Adsorption' || result[5] === 'Desorption' && results[6] === 'PREC'
```

...could be structured as follows:

```
[{
  productID: 'Adsorption'
}, {
  productID: 'Desorption',
  collection: 'PREC'
}]
```

So one object in such a filter structure represents AND-conditions. Other objects represent alternatives, so they relate to each other with a logical OR.

Here is how such a filter object can be applied to the data set:

```js
function transform(data) { // from the code above
  let [header, ...rows] = data;
  return rows.map(row => Object.fromEntries(
    row.map((val, i) => [header[i], val])
  ));
}

function filter(rows, conditions) {
  return rows.filter(row =>
    // Perform OR-operation on condition objects
    conditions.some(condition =>
      // Perform AND-operation on condition-object properties
      Object.entries(condition).every(([k, v]) => row[k] == v)
    )
  );
}

// Demo:
let data = [["docmetaID", "pathwaySeqID", "srcstrID", "accstrID", "processDescription", "productID", "collection", "doctype", "studytype"],["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Adsorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""], ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Desorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""], ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Precipitation", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]];

let conditions = [{ processDescription: 'Adsorption'}, {processDescription: 'Desorption', productID: 'PREC' }];

let rows = transform(data);
let result = filter(rows, conditions);
console.log(result);
```

### Using the original data format

Although it is best practice to work with the object array format all the way, I will provide here the code for when you have reasons to stick with the original format. The format for the filter object will remain the same:

```js
function filter(data, conditions) {
  let [header, ...rows] = data;
  let headerToIndex = Object.fromEntries(header.map((name, i) => [name, i]));
  return [header, ...rows.filter(row =>
    // Perform OR-operation on condition objects
    conditions.some(condition =>
      // Perform AND-operation on condition-object properties
      Object.entries(condition).every(([k, v]) => row[headerToIndex[k]] == v)
    )
  )];
}

// Demo:
let data = [["docmetaID", "pathwaySeqID", "srcstrID", "accstrID", "processDescription", "productID", "collection", "doctype", "studytype"],["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Adsorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""], ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Desorption", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""], ["1", "108", "Feces, Brownwater", "Process Residual Stream", "Precipitation", "PREC", "SANAGRI", "JOUR", ""]];

let conditions = [{ processDescription: 'Adsorption'}, {processDescription: 'Desorption', productID: 'PREC' }];

let result = filter(data, conditions);
console.log(result);
```

The output includes the header row. If you don't want that, then just omit `[header, ...` and the closing bracket from the `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the final format I need is in the original format as that then gets passed to another JS function that requires the "CSV" type format. Plus aren't you adding additional data to create the new object orientated format and therefore taking up more memory?

Comment: No, there is no additional data. If you are worried about the property names: JavaScript engines are optimised to deal with that: objects are at the very core of JavaScript. But I will add a section that performs the operation on the original format... even though I would urge you to work with objects all the way.

Comment: Added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set an array of conditions and check every one.

You could achieve this by doing it so:

```
// let conditions be a two dimensional array with
// the table column to check and the value to compare to
let conditions = [];
conditions.push([5, "Adsorption"]);
conditions.push([5, "Desorption"]); 

array.filter((row, index) => {
   // skip the header with the index-test

   // and example
   return index && conditions.every((condition) => row[condition[0]] == condition[1]);

   // or example
   return index && conditions.filter((condition) => row[condition[0]] == condition[1]).length

   // or example (faster, doesn't have to to test all)
   for (let i in conditions)
     if (index && row[conditions[i][0]] == conditions[i][1])
       return true;
   return false;
})
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Perhaps I should have been clearer in my question. Some of the filters will be AND and some will be OR, how would I incorporate that requirement?

Comment: Why do you use index && here? Why is it necessary?